# android separate wifi and mobile data usage by app (uid) using getUidRxBytes / getUidTxBytes

Tags: android, networking, mobile

I am trying to figure out how to retrieve separate mobile (cellular/3G/4G) data usage and separate WIFI usage broken down by application. I see that android.trafficstats has  getUidRxBytes / getUidTxBytes but documentation says it provides bytes used from all interfaces.

My question is, is there any way to separate what was used on Wifi and mobile? If so, how can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an idea to solve it...

Step 1. Check network connect type in Mobile of WiFi (use ConnectivityManager, NetworkInfo etc...).

Step 2. Use SQLite to record data (getUidRxBytes+getUidTxBytes) and tag(if connection with wifi, write 'w' to SQLite), example:

－－－－－－－－－－－－

_id｜　uid｜　data｜　tag

1　　123　　10　　　 w

2　　123　　50

－－－－－－－－－－－－

Step 3. Finally, uid of 123 this app's mobile usage data is 40 (50-10)

Have any suggestion, welcome to sharing...

Answer (score 3):

You can use getMobileRxPackets() to break down mobile/wifi data. Check out [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can check how the android achieve the getUidRxBytes / getUidTxBytes method.

In the android_net_TrafficStats.cpp, they all read the files which are in "/proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_fmt" and "/proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stat".

In the "/proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stat", you can get the bytes the uid used which android separate wifi and mobile data.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:
I don't believe there is a way to do this unless your app is signed with the system key.

Long Answer:
I've also been trying to do this.  The ICS settings app does it, in the Data Usage section.  I've dug around the ICS source code a bit, but so far I haven't been able to tell exactly how its done.  Its not in the native implementation of the TrafficStats class.

I believe the logging portion of it is in the NetworkStats and NetworkStatsHistory classes of the ICS source.  The NetworkStatsService seems to collect the data.  I haven't tracked down the exact methods, or file on disc which they are accessing yet.